# Dynamically change datatables background color for all rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have implemented datatables on a table in which some rows should have a different background color than others, identified by a **CSS class**.

I want to change the background color of a row whenever the pointer is hovered over it. For this I am using the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
         "bJQueryUI": true,
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "fnRowCallback": function () {
             // Assigning colors to inactive rows
             $('tr').each(function () {
                 if ($(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
                     $(this).css('background', '#fccfcf');
                     $(this).find('.sorting_1').each(function () {
                         $(this).css('background', '#fccfcf');
                     });
                 }
             });
         },
         "aoColumns": /*3 column table*/
         [{
             "bSearchable": false,
             "bSortable": false
         },
         null, null]
     });

     // Dynamically binding hover function to change color and pointer on mouse hover 
     oTable.$('tr').hover(function () {
         previousBackground = $(this).css('background-color');
         $(this).css('background-color', '#e2ebff');
         $(this).find('.sorting_1').each(function () {
             $(this).css('background', '#e2ebff');
         });
         $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
     }, function () {
         $(this).css('background-color', previousBackground);
         $(this).find('.sorting_1').each(function () {
             $(this).css('background', previousBackground);
         });
     });
 });
```

On first load, the table gives the desired result. However when I sort any column, everything falls apart. Some columns display background colors properly, some display only partially. How can I change the background colors without letting the sorting classes affect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only acts on style. You should use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) to do that.

There is a special `:hover` selector in CSS to allow you to change style when the mouse points over an element:

```
#myTable tbody tr.inactive,
#myTable tbody tr.inactive td.sorting_1 {
    background-color: #fccfcf
}
#myTable tbody tr:hover,
#myTable tbody tr:hover td.sorting_1 {
    background-color: #e2ebff;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

And drop both your `fnRowCallback` and `.hover()` callbacks.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhcnd/)

Comment: Datatable applies some of its own CSS after the sorting is done. So using only CSS will not work. I will have to change the CSS dynamically after the datatable is completed.